# How do i web scrap i-frame with chrome webscrapper extension?

Tags: web-scraping, web

Hello i'm trying to webscrapping i-frame content using the chrome webscrapper extension. I need to extract only the blue names in the content.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC7uz.png)

Screenshot of the code [Screenshot code html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDTC3.png)

I try webscrapping using the web scrapper chrome extension.
This is the html code :

```
<iframe width="100%" ng-src="/referentiel-localisation/#/cget/selectionLocalisation?jwtKey=jwt-cget-portail-agent-aides&amp;hierarchies=HIERARCHIEQUARTIER&amp;selected=Bys3d64bFQ:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER,Hkpnu6EZK7:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER,ByC3upVWtX:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER,Hk33daEbtQ:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER&amp;readOnly=true&amp;changedByContribution=false&amp;theme=agents" id="localisationIframe" scrolling="no" src="/referentiel-localisation/#/cget/selectionLocalisation?jwtKey=jwt-cget-portail-agent-aides&amp;hierarchies=HIERARCHIEQUARTIER&amp;selected=Bys3d64bFQ:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER,Hkpnu6EZK7:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER,ByC3upVWtX:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER,Hk33daEbtQ:HIERARCHIEQUARTIER&amp;readOnly=true&amp;changedByContribution=false&amp;theme=agents" style="overflow: hidden; height: 433px;"></iframe>
```

The code of one the blue content is what i'm trying to get  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C6vP.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)